# image or class appended to list

Tags: python, list, chess

I have been trying to detect a winner just by letting a messagebox appear, I am thinking about appending all destroyed pieces to a list and then if the king is there win is detected, I am struggling with whether it is the class GUIKing or the image of the piece that is appended to the list.

```
def destroy_piece(self, piece):
        """ Removes piece from the canvans and click-handler
            automatily called by move_piece
        """
        img1=piece.get_img_int(0)
        img2=piece.get_img_int(1)
        
        del self._on_clicks[str(img1)]
        del self._on_clicks[str(img2)]
        
        self.delete(piece.get_img_int(0))
        self.delete(piece.get_img_int(1))
        
        self.destroyed_pieces = [] 
        self.destroyed_pieces.append(piece)
```

Answer (score 0):

The list should contain an object, so the GUIKing class instance should be the way to go. But it depends how you do it in your whole program. You have to keep it consistent and always work with the object/classes. This is better.

But for a quick fix you could use this:

```
def destroy_piece(self, piece):
        """ Removes piece from the canvans and click-handler
            automatily called by move_piece
        """
        img1=piece.get_img_int(0)
        img2=piece.get_img_int(1)
        
        del self._on_clicks[str(img1)]
        del self._on_clicks[str(img2)]
        
        self.delete(piece.get_img_int(0))
        self.delete(piece.get_img_int(1))
        
        ## self.destroyed_pieces = [] ## move this in the class __init__
        self.destroyed_pieces.append(piece)
        
        ##for elem in self.destroyed_pieces: ## remove this unneccessary line
        if "bk.png" or "wk.png" in self.destroyed_pieces:
            messagebox.showinfo("WINNER")
```

Comment: Okay, do you have any solution of it? for elem in self.destroyed_pieces:
                                                                 if GUIKing in self.destroyed_pieces:
                                                                        messagebox.showinfo("WINNER")

Comment: It depends. How do you store the board state ? and the existing pieces ? The code is not complete enough to give an answer, as it may affect other parts of the code.

Comment: Is is t already working the way you didi it ? If yes ... this would probably be a long task to change all to use objects. ANyway you just use the image name, not the full size image in the list ... so the overhead is not so big ... just a question of coding style, I suppose

Comment: I tested it but it is not working actually so I am not coming any further actually

Comment: By storing do you mean how the pieces is out on the gameboard?

Comment: I added a modified version of def destroy_piece(self, piece) in my proposed solution. 
You have to init self.destroyed_pieces = []  in  __init__(), not here... and test with the new method. This keeps the way you started with the image names ... as I do not have your full code. Is it working better ?

Comment: What is it that I am supposed to init? My bad for not understanding

Comment: You store the board state somewhere right ? You probably have a GUIKing object created somewhere ? with its name and example, it should be easier to show how to add it to the list  if needed. Withou it is impossible to help more

Comment: Could you show how you call def destroy_piece(self, piece): what is piece like and created ?

Comment: I saw you edited your question ... you add "piece" to your list, this seems good idea. But you do not show what is "piece"? Is it now working for you ? or what is your code and question now ? Why do you reset the list to [] each time the function is called ?

Comment: I moved the list to the class constructor of the function but now it is not appending to the list

Comment: self.destroyed_pieces.append(piece)

Comment: As I said : "self.destroyed_pieces = [] " this reset the list content at each call. Maybee you want to remove this line and put it in the constructor ? I do not see any reason to reset it each time a piece is captured. This explain why the list will always have 0 et 1 piece. Do you really want this behaviour ? COuld you update the code in the question if you changed it ?